# How can I increase my elemental resistances

Tags: diablo-iii

I know that the *intelligence* stat increases elemental resistance. So casters seem to have a nice advantage there.

But what about the other classes? My friend is playing a Monk and while he has good defense, elemental attacks really kill him fast (late Normal, early Nightmare difficulty).

So the question is: What are the ways to obtain elemental resistances other than having to look for `+Intelligence` items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the game more simple at start some types of unneeded(at the time) pre/surfixes are not available at Normal. Elemental resistance are some of the magic bonuses you can not get on Normal, so you just need to keep playing on Nightmare and you should start seeing them pop up.

Comment: I just saw that there are items with *+ elemental resistances* ([example](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/the-murlocket)). But you're saying that there are also some magical properties that only appear at a given level (or maybe item-level)? Could you add a link/source to your answer?

Comment: @bummzack It is from a video of Jay Wilson at Blizzcon. I can't find it right now, will update my answer when I get time later today.

Comment: I personally like this, I always thought the +3% Cold resistance items in D2 Normal were stupid.  Given the damage ranges, that probably didn't even protect you from 1 point of damage.